# How to make CSS Sticky work with Flex issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an HTML structure where I can't seem to get the CSS position sticky working.

I think it because it's within the `aside` container. If I make `aside` sticky it works.

I want the `.product-info` div to be sticky and when it hits the div `.content-other` it unsticks.

Unless with flex I could move out `.personal-info` and `.product-info` from within the `aside` and have them sit to the right on top of each other? Like

`content | Personal info
         | Product info`

Then not bother having the wrapping aside? Not sure how to stack these like this though with flex.

Here is a demo: https://codepen.io/pbul2004/pen/xxZKyVR

Cheers

Comment: this is not how sticky works, https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46 , its a great article to go through

Comment: you might need to write some JS scroll event for the "unsticking" part

Comment: Would sticky not work if it was possible to stack the sidebar items? When you put sticky on the aside it works fine. Or remove the aside and have 2 separate divs on the right stacked?

Comment: @John, yeah sticky must be a direct child of the body

Comment: ok, I might make a new question to get help with stacking those 2 divs on the right with Flex as i can't for the life of me figure that out

Comment: try using float and % in the widths